# Logic error in program which uses trapezoidal approximation to find the area under curve

Tags: java, class, static, compiler-errors, logic

Can anyone find why this is this class wont run? I've made some error or another, but I can't seem to see the error. I instantiate an object and print what should be its area using what I believe is the proper notation to return the value I desire. The information in the object should evaluate to ~7.2.

```
public class TrapApx
{
    private double x1;
    private double x2;
    private double distance;
    private double numberOfSections;
    private double changeInX;
    private double area = 0;

    public TrapApx(double firstX, double secondX, double numOfSec)
    {
        x1 = firstX;
        x2 = secondX;
        numberOfSections = numOfSec;
    }

    public double distance()
    {
        return distance = x2 - x1;
    }

    public double changeX()
    {
        return changeInX = distance / numberOfSections;
    }

    public double funcX(double x)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(x-1);
    }

    public double areaApx()
    {
        for(double x = x1; x < x2; x += changeInX)
        {
            area += (funcX(x) + funcX(x + changeInX))/2 * changeInX;
        }
        return area;
    }
}

public class TrapApxTest
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        TrapApx one = new TrapApx(1, 6, 5);
        System.out.println(one.areaApx());
    }
}
```

and I tried to see if something was not functioning with one of my variables or their mutations, so I created this static class with no objects and tested it procedurally, and it returned the proper answer.

```
public class tester
{
    public static double funcX(double x)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(x-1);
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        double x1 = 1,
               x2 = 6,
               distance = x2 - x1,
               numberOfSections = 5,
               changeInX = distance / numberOfSections,
               area = 0;

        for(double x = x1; x < x2; x += changeInX)
        {
            area += (funcX(x) + funcX(x + changeInX))/2 * changeInX;
        }

        System.out.println(area);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Debug your application with an IDE and tell us what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never run the `distance()` method, so the `distance` field stays at zero.  It's a really terrible idea to give a field and a method the same name.

Comment: `one.distance();`
`one.changeX();`
Right? That turned out the proper output, silly me, I forgot. Have you got any suggestions concerning naming or program layout, now that it functions (outside of the distance method)? Thanks again, for the assistance.

Comment: Umm, that's a very broad question.  I could write pages and pages in answer to that.  There's a lot that you could do better with this program, but I'll mention only a couple of things.  Firstly, a method will either calculate and return a value, or it will change an object in some way; but usually not both.  With some of your methods, you're changing the value of a field AND returning that value; and I think you've got confused about which is important in which case.  Also, having different classes for different concerns is good.  Here, you've got calculating the function `Math.sqrt(x-1)` ...

Comment: ... all in the same class as the one that deals with the trapezoid algorithm.  If you're using Java 8, I would recommend having a single class that implements the trapezoid algorithm; and pass the function that you're trying to integrate as a lambda.